# SSRS Data Between 2 dates

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am working on an SSRS report in Visual Studio.  I have my dataset and data source all setup.  Records are being pulled from my source.  So far what I have done is added a table with a few columns.  One of these columns is storing a `DateTime` variable.  I set formatting for that column to `short date`  I then went into `Tablex Properties` and choose filter.  I then choose my `DateTime` column, set the operator to `Between`.  Then for the values I used:

```
=CDate("12/1/" & CStr(Year(Today)-1))
=CDate("12/1/" & CStr(Year(Today)-1))

Starting Dates will be listed as:
12/1/2015
12/1/2015
12/1/2015
12/2/2015
12/2/2015
12/2/2015
12/8/2015
12/15/2015
12/20/2015

What I will get back will be:
12/1/2015
12/1/2015
12/2/2015
12/2/2015
12/8/2015
12/15/2015
```

So the above that I found doing a google search is returning values just not all of them.  I don't have any other filters applied in my report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I found that I was having was the amount of data that I was trying to return was to much and it all wasn't loaded yet.  I am changing my xml to filter the data before hand and then having mulitple datasets for the report.  The expressions above are the correct ones.